# Flutter flexible layout, vertical overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm starting out my first real world flutter app and so far I cannot wrap my head around how to solve this very basic use case I have.

I find various information online but none has really solved it yet. The use case seems so common to me that there has to a good standard way of doing this.

I have a column layout. To illustrate this there is a logo (blue), a form (red), a button (green) and some custom navigation at the bottom (black).

[image]

Here is the code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const Placeholder(
                color: Colors.blue,
                fallbackHeight: 100.0,
              ),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 32.0),
                child: Placeholder(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  fallbackHeight: 300.0,
                ),
              ),
              const Spacer(),
              Column(
                children: [
                  const Placeholder(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    fallbackHeight: 40.0,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
                    child: const Placeholder(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fallbackHeight: 40.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm running this on a Pixel 5 emulator. The sizes are not 100% accurate but good enough to explain the scenario I think.

This screen is part of a flow with similar screens, hence I want to layout the custom navigation and button from the bottom and up so to speak. I.e. I want the button and the nav to be at the same position when I navigate to the next screen.

The same is true with the logo and the main content from the top. Therefor I put a spacer in between that will take up the space in between.

To the issue. I have some validation within the form. When pressing the button and breaking the validation the form will display a bunch of messages below each field. I simulate this by increasing the height of the form placeholder to 500.

[image]

So now all the components won't fit in the screen anymore and I get some overflow at the bottom. Nothing strange.
When researching the most idiomatic way to solve this I find it is to add a `SingleChildScrollView` which make sense.

But adding a `SingleChildScrollView` breaks the code since I have a `Spacer` in there. And I understand that part. Since we now say that "take up as much space as you want, I will make it scrollable" we have infinit of space at our disposal. At the same time the `Spacer` basically says, "I'll push everything down as much as I can until there are no space left". So this also make sense. Let's remove the spacer.

Here is the code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const Placeholder(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  fallbackHeight: 100.0,
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 32.0),
                  child: Placeholder(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    fallbackHeight: 500.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    const Placeholder(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      fallbackHeight: 40.0,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
                      child: const Placeholder(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fallbackHeight: 40.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It works as expected. I get no error and I can scroll to see the button and navigation.

Now to the sum this up. What happens when my form goes back to it's original height, 300px? Of course since the spacer is removed I don't have that behaviour I want anymore where the button and nav is based from the bottom. They are now pulled up to the form instead. And of course, this also make sense.

[image]

I understand why all the different scenarios act as they do. But how can I then create a flexible layout where some stuff are positioned based from the bottom and some from the top but still protect against the overflow?

Do I have to start calculating when and if any overflow is going to occur and dynamically add a scroll view? I haven't gone down that route yet because I was hoping there was a more declarative, standard way of dealing with this.

Comment: What do you exact want

Comment: I was hoping that my explanation was good enough but it is hard, I know. I want the first image to be true at all times until the form increase the height (due to new content, error message) then I don't want an overflow error but rather a scrollable view.

But I'm open to any solution that keeps the layout in the first image and doesn't break when the form increase in height. Whatever implementation solves that and still works when the content doesn't fit on the screen is interesting.

Comment: You want to second image like output with scrollable, is it correct?

Comment: Only when the content is overflowing. Otherwise I want the layout in the first image. But again, the first image is the layout I want that is first priority. And the I want protection against the overflow occurring when the form increase in height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Demo'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: ListView(children: [
                Text('Logo'),
               SizedBox(height: 1000,), //large placeholder
                Text('bottom')
              ],)),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('Your button'))
        ],
      ),
    );
```

So basically you start filling up your screen from the bottom with your button and then with the expanded widget you fill up the rest of the available space, wchich you fill up with a scrollable widget like ListView (which is better than SingleChildscrollView for more than one widget as it's child.

To apply this concept to you code:

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      const Placeholder(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        fallbackHeight: 100.0,
                      ),
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 32.0),
                        child: Placeholder(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          fallbackHeight: 500.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                const Placeholder(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  fallbackHeight: 40.0,
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
                  child: const Placeholder(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fallbackHeight: 40.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising. I will try it out a bit, but also wait for other answers if there are any before marking anything as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you. add your column to `SingleChildScrollView`

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const Placeholder(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  fallbackHeight: 100.0,
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 32.0),
                  child: Placeholder(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    fallbackHeight: 900.0,
                  ),
                ),
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      const Placeholder(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        fallbackHeight: 40.0,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
                        child: const Placeholder(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fallbackHeight: 40.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      // If you want your bottom widget is constant then used bottomSheet (uncomment below bottomSheet code)
      /*
      bottomSheet: Container(
          height: 40,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
     */
    );
```

Comment: That will unfortunately not help when the form has it's regular height (300 px in my example). Then the layout from image 1 won't be kept. It will rather be image 3 which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: you want to scroll your first two widgets only then remove SingleChildScrollView from secode column